# Remove duplicates with additional requirements

Tags: numpy, duplicates, unique

I have three columns `(x,y,m)`, where `x` and `y` are coordinates and `m` is the measurement. There are some duplicates, which are defined to be same `(x,y)`. Among those duplicates, I then rank them by the measurement `m`, I only pick one of the duplicates with minimum `m`. Here is an example:

```
x = np.array([1,1,2,2,1,1,2])
y = np.array([1,2,1,2,1,1,1])
m = np.array([10,2,13,4,6,15,7])
```

there are three duplicates with same coordinates `(1,1)`, among the three, the minimum `m` is 6. There are two duplicates with same coordinates `(2,1)`, among the two, the minimum `m` is 7. So the final result I want is:

```
x = np.array([1,2,1,2])
y = np.array([2,2,1,1])
m = np.array([2,4,6,7])
```

The `numpy.unique` can not handle such situation. Any great thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use pandas here for a cleaner solution -

```
import pandas as pd

In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'m':m})

In [46]: out_df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['x','y'])['m'].idxmin()]

# Format #1 : Final output as a 2D array
In [47]: out_df.values
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 1, 6],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 7],
       [2, 2, 4]])

# Format #2 : Final output as three separate 1D arrays
In [50]: X,Y,M = out_df.values.T

In [51]: X
Out[51]: array([1, 1, 2, 2])

In [52]: Y
Out[52]: array([1, 2, 1, 2])

In [53]: M
Out[53]: array([6, 2, 7, 4])
```

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, I run your commands, get almost same results. The only difference is that when I run `out_df.values`, the column of `m` is in the first. I wonder why there will be such difference?

Comment: @HuanianZhang Yeah that ordering is based on how dataframe constructs the headers. One way to solve the order issue would be with something like `idx = df.groupby(['x','y'])['m'].idxmin().values` and then using `idx` to select values off `x,y,m`.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, I also found it out by your command above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import collections
x = np.array([1,1,2,2,1,1,2])
y = np.array([1,2,1,2,1,1,1])
m = np.array([10,2,13,4,6,15,7])
coords = [str(x[i]) + ',' + str(y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
results = collections.OrderedDict()
for coords, m in zip(coords, m):
    if coords not in results:
        results[coords] = m
    else:
        if m < results[coords]:
            results[coords] = m
x = np.array([int(key.split(',')[0]) for key, _ in results.items()])
y = np.array([int(key.split(',')[1]) for key, _ in results.items()])
m = np.array([value for _, value in results.items()])
```

Comment: Thank you @ashemag.